# Mercurial not configured correctly

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have recently updated to eclipse juno. I have also updated mercurial to its latest version, but it is still giving me problems. The mercurial plugin tells :"Unsupported hg version:1.9.3. Expected is at least2.0.0." but its already updated(see pic).

If I try to commit, it automatically opens preferences window, which gives message :"Mercurial is not configured correctly.Run 'hg debuginstall' to analyse.".

When I do that, it says:"no username supplied". Then I run "hg -y debuginstall", which says, no problems were detected.

Everything that I mentioned is depicted in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to this issue, but maybe useful for other people looking up the error message: there is a newer issue producing the same error message when using JDK 7, Update 21. The plugin will choke on spaces in paths for the external executable. The workaround is to use the DOS path (e.g. C:\Progra~1\...). See https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/414/mercurial-is-not-configured-correctlyrun for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck the option labelled `Use default (built-in) Mercurial executable`; then in the text box labelled `Mercurial executable` below, you can enter the full path to the `hg.exe` under your TortoiseHg 2.5 installation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed Mercurial Eclipse Plugin. I find the configuration file "Mercurial.ini" in the mercurial installation folder. In my case, the path of that folder is "E:\eclipse\plugins\com.intland.hgbinary.win32_2.3.2\os\win32". Edit the configuration file with notepad and add the line "username = your-user-name" where your-user-name is free to choose. I hope it would help.